# select2 drop down box incompatible with jQuery date picker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-select2

I have a simple form field where I have searchable drop down boxes followed by a date input field with datepicker().   For select2, i have the following script:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { $("#e22").select2({
placeholder: "Select a Pet",
allowClear: true
}); });
</script>
```

For datepicker, I have:

```
<script>
function datepickerinit()
{
$("#payment_date").datepicker();
$("#order_provided_date").datepicker();
$("#order_date").datepicker();                      
}
</script>
```

It seems that the if I have the first script with the jquery source in the drop down it works but disables the date picker and vice versa.  I am fairly new at this and I am sure that I just have something in the wrong place. The head is in an include header.php file and if I put the script in there, the drop down does not work so the scripts are in the body. Is there a way to have both the select2 searchable drop down box and a date picker input?

Comment: try this :   `$(document).ready(
 function() { $("#e22").select2({
 placeholder: "Select a Pet",
 allowClear: true
 });

 $("#payment_date").datepicker();
 $("#order_provided_date").datepicker();
 $("#order_date").datepicker();                      
});`

Comment: Thanks for the help; I put the first script reference to jquery in the head section and it now works. I think that I must have an old jquery file that must have been incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/234/) code with datepicker and select2.  Hope this helps.

HTML:

```
<p>Date:
    <input id="datepicker" type="text"/> 
    <input type="hidden" id="test" />
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#datepicker").datepicker();     
var test = $('#test');
$(test).select2({
    data:[
        {id:0,text:"enhancement"},
        {id:1,text:"bug"},
        {id:2,text:"duplicate"},
        {id:3,text:"invalid"},
        {id:4,text:"wontfix"}
    ],
    width: "300px"
});

});
```